# IntelliJ or WebStorm keymaps don't work in Debian 9

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, intellij-plugin

I installed WebStorm and IntelliJ plugin for it.

I can't use any shortcuts in WebStorm such as `Ctrl+Alt+S` for settings.
I double-check that VIM-Emulator is enabled in `Tools → VIM-Emulator` and looked in `Editor → Vim-Emulation` tab, and change shortcuts what i need to VIM. Nothing happens even after restarting WebStorm and nothing after change handler to IDE also.

Reinstalling IntelliJ plugin give zero effect.
Please help. I need my shortcuts from Windows such as `Ctrl+C`

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that

1. `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V` in your current keymap selected in **Settings | Keymap** mean **Copy** and **Paste**
2. You don't have any key mappings in your `~/.vimrc`
3. Handlers for conflicted `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V` are set to *IDE* in **Settings | Editor | Vim Emulation**